# how to Insert multiple records in a invoice and a details MySQL tables with Python?

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to record the invoices of some tenants I got in a MySQL database for a real estate agency. The thing is that these invoices must be saved in two tables: the invoices and details tables. The code I got at this moment works good saving the information needed for the first table (tenants' invoices), but I don't really know how to write for the second one.

The table to save tenants' invoices is called 'factura_arre' and it contains the info about: number of the invoice, date, the tax, total and others.

```
MariaDB> desc factura_arre;
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| fa_num    | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| c_cod     | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| fa_fecha  | datetime   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| fa_iva    | float      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| fa_total  | float      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| fa_estado | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| fa_notas  | blob       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

And the table to save the details of the the previous table (factura_arre) is called 'fa_detalles', and has informations such as the number of the invoice, description and value.

```
MariaDB> desc fa_detalles;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| fad_id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| fa_num    | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| fad_desc  | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| fad_valor | float        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

To make this happen I use this Pyhon function, and it works good, but what do I have to add for recording the details in the other table?

```
def monthly_invoices():
    #YEAR/MONTH OF THE SYSTEM
    fechasys = time.strftime("%Y%m")
    #LAST YEAR/MONTH OF MYSQL INVOICES
    cursor.execute("SELECT EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM fa_fecha)FROM factura_arre;")
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    for fechasys in results:
        showerror("","This operation is not allow for current month!")
        break
    else:
        #QUERY THE VALUE OF IVA LEGAL TAX
        cursor.execute("SELECT ivajuridico FROM configuracion;")
        dato1 = cursor.fetchall()
        #QUERY THE INFORMATION OF THE TENANTS
        cursor.execute("SELECT c_cod, now(), relacionip.i_cod, i_vlrenta, a_tpersona FROM contratos INNER JOIN relacionip ON contratos.r_id = relacionip.r_id INNER JOIN inmuebles ON relacionip.i_cod = inmuebles.i_cod INNER JOIN arrendatarios ON contratos.a_cc = arrendatarios.a_cc;")
        dato2 = cursor.fetchall()
        connect.commit()
        for a in dato1:
            #GET THE VALUE OF THE TAX AS FLOAT
            ivaj = a[0] #16.0 (float)
            for i in dato2:
                if i[4] == 2:
                    #showinfo("","He's Legal")
                    iva = i[3]*ivaj/100 #vl arriendo*iva/100
                    total = i[3]+iva
                else:
                    #showinfo("","He's Natural")
                    iva = 0
                    total = i[3]+iva
                    try:
                        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO factura_arre(c_cod, fa_fecha, fa_iva, fa_total) values ('%s', now(), '%f', '%f')" % (i[0], iva, total))# i[0] is c_cod for the row just calculated.
                        connect.commit()
                    except:
                        pass
            showinfo('Operation', "Invoices saved!")
```

To understand tyo relationship, here's a diagram:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WFPU.png)

Comment: What is stopping you from just doing
`cursor.execute("INSERT INTO fa_detalles (fa_num, fa_desc, fa_valor) values ('%d', '%s', '%f')" % (cursor.lastrowid, description, value))`  where `description` and `value` are the appropriate values. Have you tried anything or got any errors?

Comment: @Carlos Thanks for your help, I got the idea! But what do you meant with `cursor.lastrowid`? Do I have to write it down just like that?

Comment: Hey @Carlos what about something as `INSERT INTO fa_detalles (fa_num, fa_desc, fa_valor) values ('%d', "Rent value Month: %s/%s", '%f')''' % (cursor.lastrowid, month/year, value))` where month/year come from `year = time.strftime("%Y")` and `month = time.strftime("%B")` variables?

Comment: `cursor.lastrowid` just returns the id of the last row commited to the dB, in your case `fa_num`

Comment: Well @Carlos I tried your code but the error is `NameError: global name 'value' is not defined`. I'm thinking now that maybe I need to modify my contracts table because the rent value of the property is too far from this code, and if I want to add that value here it's gonna be hard for me. Perhaps, `description` did't got that Error because I declared it before as `description = "Rent value Month: "`

Comment: well I think I misspelled `fad_valor` and `fad_desc` which could also be an issue, but obviously you need `value` to be within the scope for the insert to work.

Comment: But @Carlos, if `cursor.lastrowid` returns me just one record (the last one of fa_num), how am I gonna record the rest tenants' details. For example, If I got 4 tenants and I saved their invoices in the table, how am I going to save the details of all 4 if I just have the fa_num of the last one? This the first time I know about `cursor.lastrowid`, and that's why I ask, and still dig about it.

Comment: Can you not insert the first one to table one then to table 2, and move to the next tenant and so on?

Comment: Yeah, I could do that, but when I have about 50 tenants that's gonna be frustrating. That's also why I got at the beginning of my code the option to detect the date of the system to do this operation just once a month.